# Chosen combobox doesn't work on small device

Tags: jquery, css, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

i have 2 combobox cum textbox for searching(using chosen jquery library) in first combobox there is category, which category is selected then its product list is load in second combobox. And if the product is selecting on second combobox then the data are display in a div using ajax.

Everything is working perfectly but the problem is that when i am resizing the browser size to check responsible then some css not adjust as on resizing of browser but if i refresh then it adjust perfect.

This is not a major problem but the major problem is **i checked chosen jQuery in inspect element and i found that the div which is dynamically generated for combobox through chosen library, it is not exist there, it is not work for small device. The div doesn't generated so in my web page there is a simple selectbox(combobox) is there but it is not suggested(combobox cum textbox) combobox. So what is the solution for it?**

When i run on normal desktop size browser then there is div exist with `<select>` tag And when i run on small devices then it doesn't exist there. only the `<select>` tag is there.

**See here:**

[image]

I searched many options but i can't found the solution. Tell me easy way to do this.

Please help me if you can.

If my explanation is not accurate then sorry and you can ask me about it so i can clearly specify that what i want to say.

**Note:- It is work very well on desktop size the problem is on small size.** I think chosen jQuery doesn't call its function for some reason.

**View:-**

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script>
      $(function() {
        $('.chosen-select').chosen();
        $('.chosen-select-deselect').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
      });
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-0" style="padding:0px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="category" class="chosen-select" onchange="set_cat(this.value)" title="Select Category">
                <option value="" selected style="display:none;">Select Category</option>
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <?php
                foreach($cat as $c)
                { echo "<option value='".$c['category']."'>".$c['category']."</option>"; }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" style="padding:0px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="product">
                <select id="prod" class="chosen-select" onchange="set_prod(this.value)">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option disabled>Please select category first</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function set_cat(cat)
{
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
    });
    $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url('searching/set_cat/');?>",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: {cat:cat},
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data)
      {
        $("#product").html(data);
      }
    })
}
function searching(search_item)
{
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
    });
    $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url('searching/search_item/');?>",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: {search_item:search_item},
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data)
      {
        $("#container").html(data);
      }
    })
}
</script>
```

**Model :-**

```
function product()
    {
        $cat=$this->input->post('cat');
        $query="select cat_name, GROUP_CONCAT(pro_name) pro_name, GROUP_CONCAT(bus_name) bus_name from tbl_business where category like '".$cat."' GROUP BY cat_name";
        $r=$this->db->query($query);
        return $r->result_array();
    }
```

Controller:-

```
function set_area()
    {
        $this->load->model('searching');
        $output=$this->searching->product();
        foreach ($output as $value)
        {
            $newArr = explode(',',$value['product']);   
            foreach ($newArr as  $val)
            {
                $productArray[]  = array($value["category"]=>$val);
            }
            $newArr = explode(',',$value['seller']);   
            foreach ($newArr as  $val)
            {
                $productArray2[]=$val;
            }
        }
        if(isset($productArray))
            $result['item'] = $productArray;
        else{
            $arr=array('product'=>'Not Found');
            $result['item']=array($arr);
        }
        if(isset($productArray2))
            $result['sell'] = $productArray2;
        else{
            $arr=array('seller'=>'Not Found');
            $result['sell']=array($arr);
        }
        $result['output']=$output;
        $this->load->view('combo_product',$result); // here i display data in another view that is works fine.
    }
```

In database table like this :-

[image]

Comment: we need a fiddle or a live example

Comment: See the same example here http://jsfiddle.net/Bratzilla/XH2q7/
When the page load it works fine but set browser on small device(mobile or tablet size) and refresh the page then you can see there is a normal combobox which doesn't provide searching facility from list. I hope you understand what i want to say. Thanks.

Comment: i have find the solution here : https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2597

Comment: if you found an answer, please feel free to post it. Stack Overflow is a Question/Answer site which encourages this: read https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ hope you get anoyer upvote to pass the 15 points limitation to be able to do so...